# setdefault() or self.configure()?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have come across these two ways to create buttons with a default setting in the settings of the button to be created. My question is what advantages or disadvantages does one have over the other?
*Of course, leaving aside the way the library is imported*

**First form:**

```py
import tkinter as tk


class CalcButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault("font", ("Roboto Cn", 14))
        kwargs.setdefault("width", 3)
        kwargs.setdefault("bd", 1)
        kwargs.setdefault("relief", "ridge")
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Calculadora Basica")
mi_frame = tk.Frame(root)
mi_frame.pack()
```

**Second way:**

```py
from tkinter import *


class CalcButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.config(font=("Roboto Cn", 14))
        self.config(width=3)
        self.config(bd=1)
        self.config(relief="ridge")


root = Tk()
root.title("basic calculator")
my_frame = Frame(root)
my_frame.pack()
```

Comment: Alternate third choice: `kwargs = {"font": ("Roboto Cn", 14), "width": 3, "bd": 1, "relief": "ridge", **kwargs}`. Last definition wins when defining a `dict`, so you just unpack the original kwargs into a `dict` literal that begins with the default values; if the original `kwargs` has the same key, the value from the original is used, if it doesn't, the default is kept, matching the behavior of option #1. Option #2 is done with `kwargs.update( {"font": ("Roboto Cn", 14), "width": 3, "bd": 1, "relief": "ridge"})`, where it overrides caller values (these aren't defaults, they're locked config).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks a very good explanation, I understood it: D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two solutions you provided are not identical in behavior. The first one will establish defaults but let the caller override the defaults, the second one will unconditionally override what was passed in.

So, the advantage of one over the other depends on whether you want to accept the options specified by the user or you want to override them.

Comment: the second one will unconditionally override what was passed in.. but it is possible, using the config option again: ```.config()``` is this the wrong thing or shouldn't it be done?

Comment: @CandyGlow: you can do either. Right or wrong depends on your goal. You can call `.config` whenever you want.